# How to get bold with italic in math by using STIX package

Tags: math-mode, stix, boldsymbol

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%


\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Path = ./Fonts/TimesLTStd/ ,
UprightFont= TimesLTStd-Roman.otf ,
BoldFont=TimesLTStd-Bold.otf ,
ItalicFont=TimesLTStd-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=TimesLTStd-BoldItalic.otf
]
{TimesLTStd-Roman}

\setmathfont{STIX Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\frac{a+b}{c+d}x+ya+b&= c\int\sum\\
d+e   &= f
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

It works fine, but please suggest how to get bold and italic for numbers and text and bold for Greek symbols.

Comment: Have you heard of `\symup`, `\symbf`, `\symit`, and `\symbfit` for upright, bold, italic, and bold-italic output while in math mode?

Comment: Incidentally, the `Stix Math` package has gotten quite old and borders on being deprecated. Consider using either `XITS Math` (along with `XITS` for the main text font) or `Stix Two Math` (along with `Stix Two Text`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use `\sym...`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\alpha+\symup{\alpha}+\symbfit{\alpha}+\symbfup{\alpha}=\symbf{123}$

$\beta+\symup{\beta}+\symbfit{\beta}+\symbfup{\beta}=\symbf{123}$

\end{document}
```

The more generic `\symbf` command respects the stylistic options `unicode-math` is called with (such as `math-style=ISO`).

Avoid STIX Math, as it has incomplete tables for being really used in math. Better STIX Two Math (you can download it from stixfonts.org).

Be also aware that newer versions of `fontspec` no longer require `xunicode` and that `xltxtra` doesn't provide any good feature. The `Ligatures=TeX` option is on by default for the font selected with `\setmainfont` and that `Mapping=tex-text` does exactly the same.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, currently I'm not in system, will check ...